# symfony get request data from datatable

Tags: symfony, datatable

I have a datatable, who call in ajax my controller and create datatable like this :

```
$max = 10;
$page = 1;
        $Surv = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('surveillance');
    $users = $Surv->getRepository('t:Surveillance\Dossier')->ServerSide($page, $max);

    $output = array(
        'data' => array(),
        'recordsFiltered' => count($Surv->getRepository('t:Surveillance\Dossier')->ServerSide(0, false)),
        'recordsTotal' => count($Surv->getRepository('t:Surveillance\Dossier')->ServerSide(0, false))
    );

    foreach ($users as $O_dossier) {
        $I_idDossier = $O_dossier->getId();
        $I_idRapportLast = 1;
        $output['data'][] = [
            'multi' => "<input type='checkbox' value='".$O_dossier->getId()."' class='case-$type'/>",
            'client' => $this->_O_dossiersM->setClientForBoHomeDatatableAjax($O_dossier->getClient(), $this->get('router')),
            'dossier' => $this->_O_dossiersM->setDossierForBoHomeDatatableAjax($O_dossier, $this->get('router')),
            'type' => $O_dossier->getType()->getNom(),
            'dateD' => $this->_O_dossiersM->setDateForDatatableAjax($O_dossier->getDateDebutAt(), 'Y-m-d', $this->_s),
            'dateF' => $this->_O_dossiersM->setDateForDatatableAjax($O_dossier->getDateFinAt(), 'Y-m-d', $this->_s),
            'analyse' => $O_dossier->getAnalyse()->getType(),
            'frequence' => $this->_O_dossiersM->setFrequenceForBoHomeDatatableAjax($O_dossier->getFrequence()),
            'dateR' => $this->_O_dossiersM->setDateLastRapportForBoHomeDatatableAjax($O_dossier, $A_listeDossierWithDateLastRapport, 'Y-m-d', $this->_s),
            'action' => $this->render('m:TemplateForAjax:tableauBoDossierTdAction.html.twig', array('O_dossier' => $O_dossier, 'I_idRapportLast' => $I_idRapportLast))->getContent(),
            'cc' => $this->_O_clientsM->getCcPrenomNomByClient($O_dossier->getClient()),
            'jur' => $O_dossier->getJuriste()->getNom(),
            'isActif' => $i++//($O_dossier->getIsActif()) ? 'active' : 'inactive'
        ];
    }

    return new Response(json_encode($output), 200, ['Content-Type' => 'application/json']);
```

For $max and $ page, i need to get result and page defined by the datatable.
For example if i click on page "2" on my datatable, i would like get this data like this :

```
$request->request('page');
```

How do this ?

$request->request-all() return null...

My ajax :

```
$(function() {
    $('#user-list').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "pageLength": 10,
        "lengthMenu": [[5,10, 25, 50, -1], [5,10, 25, 50, 'All']],
        "ajax": "{{  path("surveillance_bo_dossier_home_tableau",{"type": 0, "client":client}) }}",
        "sAjaxDataProp": "data",
        "columns":[
            {data: "multi"},
            {data: "client"},
            {data: "dossier"},
            {data: "type"},
            {data: "dateD"},
            {data: "dateF"},
            {data: "analyse"},
            {data: "frequence"},
            {data: "cc"},
            {data: "dateR"},
            {data: "action"},
            {data: "jur"},
            {data: "isActif"},
        ]
    });
});

<table id="user-list">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>multi</th>
            <th>client</th>
            <th>dossier</th>
            <th>type</th>
            <th>dateD</th>
            <th>dateF</th>
            <th>analyse</th>
            <th>frequence</th>
            <th>cc</th>
            <th>dateR</th>
            <th>action</th>
            <th>jur</th>
            <th>isActif</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: How you are sending "page" via ajax ? POST, GET , query string?
If post $request->request->get('page'), GET $request->get('page') or $request->query->get('page'); Regards

Comment: I sending nothing, i thought these data was by default.
So for get the current page from datatable, i need jquery ?

Comment: how is the ajax call you mentioned?

Comment: i have edit my first post and add my ajax :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its ok my problem is resolved.
For get data : $request->get('start') and $request->get('length') i need to add i my ajax type post :

```
"ajax": {
            "url": "{{ path("surveillance_bo_dossier_home_tableau",{"type": 0, "client":client}) }}",
            "type": "POST"
        },
```

and now i can get data from my datatable

Answer (score 0):

Can you show me your javascript call from datatable ?

Because dadatable doesn't need to get the page number, you can just get a json response and it will load your data.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": '../ajax/data/arrays.txt'
    } );
} );
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Comment: i have edit my first post :).
Here my datatable need to get the page number because i use server side processing.
So for pagination i need to get length and page.
I have defined by default $max = 10, and $page = 1 so i have just 10 result by page, and always page  but i need $page = current page from datatable